# ¿Cuáles son consideradas buenas prácticas para Media Queries (CSS3)?

Tags: css3, mediaqueries

Quiero saber, de la gente que usa media queries, cual es la mejor practica: ¿sobreescribir el estilo original, o limpiar completamente el estilo de la pagina cada vez que se detecte una resolucion nueva y asi empezar de cero el diseño?..Bueno es que se me hace un poco feo sobreescribir el estilo, tener codigo duplicado (que sume mas peso a la pagina), tener que "contradecir" una sentencia anterior, etc.. En conclusion quiero saber cual es considerada una buena practica al trabajar con media queries: sobreescribir o limpiar totalmente el codigo ¿y como podria limpiarlo, es decir dejar el documento con cero estilos cuando detecte una resolucion diferente a la original? ¿se trabaja en la misma hoja de estilos o en otra?...espero que me haya explicado bien.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día colega! tratando de ponerme un poco en contexto con lo que comentas arriba... Pues a mí también me parece algo feo tener que "pisar" los estilos ya existentes (Pero habrán ocaciones donde toque hacerlo). Lo ideal para manejar los media queries es primero saber hacia qué publico va dirigido el sitio web y así elegir los breakpoints que vas a manejar.
Te dejo este articulo que me ayudo mucho cuando tuve la misma duda.
[how to choose media queries/breakoints to best support all connected devices](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/how-to-choose-media-queries-breakpoints-to-best-support-all-connected-devices)

Exitos!

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Buscaré artículos sobre "breakpoints" en español, ya que la verdad aunque tengo inglés básico no soporto leer algo que no sea en mi idioma.

Comment: Si estas en chrome puedes hacer: click derecho -> Traducir al español. Tal vez no te de la mejor de las traducciones pero podrás darte una idea general del contenido del sitio. Por otro lado, el ingles sera una de tus herramientas esenciales si has decidido tomar el camino del desarrollador. Te recomiendo usar la aplicación para celulares: Duolingo! es gratis y muy divertida.